# Connecting to MS SQL Server 2005 using FreeTDS on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, freetds

I built freetds 0.82 from macports using the +mssql variant (which sets up dblib and sets the default tds version to 8.0). I am now trying to connect to my database server (MSSQL Server 2005) using tsql, but it only works when I override the tds version to 4.2. If I set it to any other value, I get the follow error output.

```
> TDSVER=8.0 tsql -h <host> -p <port> -U <user> -P<password>
locale is "en_US.utf-8"
locale charset is "utf-8"
Msg 20017, Level 9, State -1, Server OpenClient, Line -1
Unexpected EOF from the server
Msg 20002, Level 9, State -1, Server OpenClient, Line -1
Adaptive Server connection failed
There was a problem connecting to the server
```

If i use TDSVER=4.2, it works just fine. Anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: http://jonkinney.com/articles/2009/11/23/change-locale-on-os-x-snow-leopard-for-freetds-functionality

The problem was that my locale encoding needed to be set to UTF-8

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

After that, I was able to connect with version 8.0 of the TDS protocol.